# How we can drop all index and constraint in neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, drop, neo4j-browser

I want delete all constraints in neo4j in neo4j browser.

[Her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357379/neo4j-how-to-drop-all-constraints) asked this question, but I cannot find answer that can I do with cypher.

I try this code:

```
FOREACH (n IN db.indexes() | drop constraints n)
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Didn't the first answer using apoc worked for you?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I didnt installed apoc . I now installed it worked. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [neo4j how to drop all constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357379/neo4j-how-to-drop-all-constraints)